# r ncdf4 cannot read character variable from netcdf

Tags: r, char, netcdf

I am trying to read variable from a [netcdf file](https://seafile.zfn.uni-bremen.de/f/f6fd29d7b6674d7a8f98/?dl=1) that contain characters

```
library(ncdf4)

NCFile <- nc_open('MD02_2575.age')
ncvar_get(NCFile, 'Label')
```

I expect

```
'KIA33119' 'KIA24904' 'KIA33120' 'KIA24905' 'KIA33121' 'KIA24906' 'KIA25875' 'KIA24907' 'KIA24903' 'User    ' 'User    ' 'User    ' 'User    ' 'User    '
```

based on what I get when I read the file with Matlab, but with R I get

```
[1] "KKKKKKKKKUUUUU" "IIIIIIIIIsssss" "AAAAAAAAAeeeee" "323232222rrrrr" "343434544     " "191919899     " "102020700     " "940516573     "
```

I would like to use R. This looks like an encoding issue, does anyone have a suggestion how to get read in the variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Label` is a 2D array with characters;

```
char Label(Label_Characters, Length);
```

Also `ncdump` is having difficulties in transforming this into a list of strings, for example: `ncdump -v Label MD02_2575.age` also gives the "incorrect" results:

```
 Label =
  "KKKKKKKKKUUUUU",
  "IIIIIIIIIsssss",
  "AAAAAAAAAeeeee",
  "323232222rrrrr",
  "343434544     ",
  "191919899     ",
  "102020700     ",
  "940516573     " ;
```

I wrote "incorrect", because from the NetCDF file itself it is not clear that (1) the individual characters need to be concatenated into strings, and (2) if that's the case, along which dimension the concatenation should be performed. Honestly, I'm surprised that `ncdump`, R and Matlab do this?

Just to illustrate the problem (using Python):

```
import netCDF4 as nc4

f = nc4.Dataset('MD02_2575.age')
v = f.variables['Label'][:,:]

label1 = v[:,0].tostring()  # Correct
label2 = v[0,:].tostring()  # Same as `ncdump`, `R`, ..

print(label1, label2)
```

Results in: `'KIA33119' 'KKKKKKKKKUUUUU'`

Comment: Thanks, even though this doesn't really solve my problem. Could there be 'confusion' with the length and dimension? ncvar_get and ncdump give output of length 8, whereas there are/should be 14.

Comment: I'll have a look tomorrow at work (where I have `R` installed), but as I mentioned, I'm surprised that `R` (and other languages/tools) automatically merge these character arrays. To me it seems that any tool/language should just read them as a character array, without merging them along one of the dimensions. Python simply reads it as 2D character array, which gives you the possibility to merge them correctly.

Comment: Thanks, Your suggestions pointed me to the right place. Dimension information is found in `NCFile$dim$Label_Characters$len` and `NCFile$dim$Length$len`. I needed to explicitly code this, but concatenation is then easy